# MySQL Repository for Enterprise Architect?

Tags: mysql, enterprise-architect

We are importing XML to EA. Our EAP size is growing to 1 GB and performance is a big issue.

We know internally EA uses MS Access, whose .mdb file size at max can be 2GB.

As we have lots of data in XML for which we are creating elements and putting in EA database, it is very slow.

Switching to My SQL is a better option or Trying to use DBMS query instead of using EA API??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely! I have used MySQL for large models and it works perfectly. Almost any RDBMS is better than EAP (MS Access) when you have many modelers/large repositories. The only issue with such a solution is that you need to have a central repository, which means that anyone needs fast access to it. Once you have people sitting abroad you have to think of different/additional configuration (e.g. version controlled packages or export/merge solutions).

Comment: Be sure to check which driver can be used. EA's site has it listed somewhere. There were also some settings required in the driver to have it work properly.